# css absolute position inside table-cell work everywhere except firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, css-tables

I have horizontal news which look like this:
[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9nn29/)

If you run this fiddle in Firefox, it displays different then in other browsers.
On my webpage it position random position (always same).

I have to use `position: absolute;` because I want to keep the date and buttons at the same level in all columns.

I google it but all solution doesn't work for me.

So my question is how to position in to look like [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9nn29/).

Answer (score 8):

Looks like: http://bugzil.la/203225

It was logged over 10 years ago.

As a workaround you could use a div within the TD and set that to position:relative instead of setting it on the TD directly.

Answer (score 2):

For me, it looks like you found a Bug in Firefox related to the CSS table layout. The absolute positioned elements with class `.date` and `.button` should be placed relative to the bounderies of their **relative positioned** parent element with class `.col`. But they are not in Firefox.

If you remove the property `display: table-cell;` then date and button are placed relative to their parent again, but you lose the desired table layout.

One solution to avoid this problem is to use a float layout instead of table-cell: [JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/nYS26/)

Comment: Your solution seems to be okay but it is not relevant because I need the dynamic height, but I have to avoid using javascript

Comment: Then a table based HTML structure would avoid this problem -> [link](http://jsfiddle.net/5yYc5/1/)

Comment: The solution with tables I used but the problem arises when with the responsive css converting my website for mobile devices and need these columns to be displayed one under the other.

Answer (score 0):

try this one,

```
.col {
    width: 235px;
    margin: 0px;
    border: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    vertical-align: top;
    background-color: white;
    display: table-cell;
    position: relative;
    float:left;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9nn29/3/

Comment: if I use 'float: left;' then i lose relationship between the heights of the columns